# How to create a fancy video play button with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, button

I'm writing a document for my students on latex and i want to design a fancy "play video" button with tikz or any other method to tell them that there is a video which explains more the idea. And i want to put the link in the button.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marijin said above, a way is inserting an image, and use the `\href` command from the `hyperref` package to link to a video. Here I create a Play-like button over an image as a `pic` of TikZ. Is that fancy enough ^^ You can use only the image, or only the Play button.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/whcbtqdqnwrg

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{The Beauty of
Divine Beings Dancing}
\author{Shen Yun}
\date{August 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}[t]{The Beauty of Shen Yun Performamce}
{\itshape An explosion of color and sound \ldots}

Just click to the following button to play an introducing video on Youtube
\tikzset{Play button/.pic={
\path (0,0) node{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{shenyun.png}};
\draw[blue,line width=2pt,fill=yellow] (-.5,.5)--(-.5,-.5)--(.5,0)--cycle;
}}
\begin{center}
\href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JwBQxKbzeo}{\tikz\pic{Play button};}    
\end{center}

See more at \href{www.shenyun.com}{\color{magenta} www.shenyun.com}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank very much that's exactly what i want.

Comment: @JackAlbert Nice to hear that! you can upvote and accept my answer ^^